# Update column value based on Cummulative sum of other two column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following table

**Buffer**

```
| id    | from_Time     | To_time   | v1    | v2    | v3    | time Stamp            |
|-----  |-----------    |---------  |----   |----   |----   |---------------------  |
| 104   | 10            | 11        | 9     | 8     |       | 2020-12-02 11:03:01   |
| 103   | 9             | 10        | 10    | 11    |       | 2020-12-02 10:03:01   |
| 102   | 8             | 9         | 13    | 13    |       | 2020-12-02 09:03:01   |
| 101   | 7             | 8         | 12    | 11    |       | 2020-12-02 08:03:01   |
| 100   | 6             | 7         | 10    | 8     |       | 2020-12-02 07:03:01   |
| 99    | 5             | 6         | 0     | 0     |       | 2020-12-02 06:03:01   |
| 98    | 4             | 5         | 0     | 0     |       | 2020-12-02 05:03:01   |
| 97    | 3             | 4         | 0     | 0     |       | 2020-12-02 03:03:15   |
| 96    | 2             | 3         | 0     | 0     |       | 2020-12-02 04:03:02   |
| 95    | 1             | 2         | 0     | 0     |       | 2020-12-02 02:03:01   |
| 94    | 0             | 1         | 0     | 0     |       | 2020-12-02 01:03:00   |
| 93    | 23            | 0         | 0     | 0     | 2     | 2020-12-02 00:03:00   |
| 92    | 22            | 23        | 0     | 4     | 2     | 2020-12-01 23:03:01   |
| 91    | 21            | 22        | 14    | 13    | 6     | 2020-12-01 22:03:00   |
| 90    | 20            | 21        | 10    | 8     | 5     | 2020-12-01 21:03:00   |
| 89    | 19            | 20        | 7     | 5     | 3     | 2020-12-01 20:03:01   |
| 88    |               |           |       |       |       |                       |
| 87    |               |           |       |       |       |                       |
| 86    |               |           |       |       |       |                       |
| 85    | 23            | 0         | 0     | 0     | 1     | 2020-12-01 01:03:00   |
```

I would like to write an update query to update the column v3.
column V3 is calculated as following

Previous Day value between 23 and 0  + cummulative total of colum V1 for today's date -  cummulative total of colum V2 for today's date

Example for an ID 91

cummulative total of V1 is 31
cummulative toatl of V2 is 26
Previous Day value between 23 and 0 is 1

so the value of V3 for ID 91 equals 1+31-26 = 6

I would like to write an update query with a where clause to update the data for an ID from 104 to 100.

I am able to get a new value of V3 using following query

```
select   T1.id,
    T1.from_time,
    T1.To_time,
    T1.v1
     ,T1.v2
     ,T1.cumm_v1,
     T1.cumm_v2
     ,T1.cumm_v1-T1.cumm_v2 + (
       select v3 from Buffer where CAST([time Stamp] as DATE)  = '20201202' and from_time = 23 and To_time = 0) 
       as V3_New
from (
SELECT 
  id,
  from_time,
  To_time,
  v1,
  v2,
  [time Stamp]
    ,SUM(v1) OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS cumm_v1
    ,SUM(v2) OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS cumm_v2
FROM Buffer where CAST([time Stamp]  as DATE)  = '20201202'
       ) as T1
```

I am getting problem to convert it into an update query.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/abaa1/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update T1
set v3 = 
T1.cumm_v1-T1.cumm_v2 + (
       select v3 from Buffer where CAST([time Stamp] as DATE)  = '20201202' and from_time = 23 and To_time = 0) 
       --as V3_New
from (
SELECT 
  id,
  from_time,
  To_time,
  v1,
  v2,
  [v3], --<-- for the update
  [time Stamp]
    ,SUM(v1) OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS cumm_v1
    ,SUM(v2) OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS cumm_v2
FROM Buffer where CAST([time Stamp]  as DATE)  = '20201202'
       ) as T1
where id between 100 and 104 --ID from 104 to 100.
```

Comment: why it updating all the rows even if i have between in query. I have changed where caluse to t1.id between 100 and 104 but still it updating all rows. any idea?

Comment: just check the messages pane in ssms (rows affected) or include `select @@rowcount` right after the update statement. For your example (fiddle): `(5 row(s) affected)` for the update (because there are 5 rows with id between 100 and 104)

Comment: yes i have checked it gives 200 rows affected.

Comment: i have to use the Alias as table name to update and instead of that i have taken a table name that's why it's updating whole table. Thanks . it works now.